# Is there any way to keep a hover/mouseover tooltip open on screen without hovering over it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, mouseover

I'm new here and I hope this is the appropriate place to ask this. I know very little about javascript or other programming languages so you might need to go easy on me.

Is there any possible way to keep a mouseover tooltip on screen even after I moved my mouse away on a public site that isn't mine? I'm trying to figure this out on a chatting site where you can post comments and see who liked each comment but you have to hover over it with a mouse to see a tooltip popup that shows the usernames of who liked the comment. I would link you the site but it requires you to make an account so instead I can link you guys the source code in case it is necessary. The only thing I was able to do was inspect element/debugger and look at some of the javascript/jquery code the site uses and that's about it lol.

So is there a way I can tamper around with the javascript? Of course I only want this to be temporarily and on just one page. My goal is to copy and paste all the text from the page including the ones in the tooltips. Maybe there is a way to show all the tooltip popups as text on the page? I'd appreciate some help. Sorry if I sound totally clueless!

Here is the part of the code that involves the tooltip:

```
<div class="si-ch-like-box">    
    <div class="si-ch-like wttip pointer" data-name="Like" data-loaded="0" data-active="0" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="ttip-wrap tw6684925 borRad none" data-class-id="6684925" style="display: none; width: 28px; bottom: 34px; left: -15px; visibility: visible;">
            <div class="ttip-text">Like</div>
                <div class="ttip-arr" style="left: 16px;"></div><div class="ttip-arr-fix" style="left: 16px;"></div></div></div>                                        
    <div class="like-popup-box posRel pointer" onmouseover="initLikeBox(this,'#wall_44715839',8,44715839)" onclick="loadLikersGlobal(this,'#wall_44715839',8,44715839)">    
            <div class="si-ch-like-nbr  bold ">1</div>                                      
                <div class="borRad posAbs like-boxes none" style="left: -53px; top: -40px; display: none;">
                    <div class="like-people-block borRad"><img src="images/loading-1.gif" width="15" border="0"></div>
             <div class="like-people-tooltip">&nbsp;</div></div></div>
```

Comment: What is the page/site. it the tooltip is a `hover` based tip. You could potentially use developer tools to force 'hover'

Comment: in chrome, right click on that element then click inspect to open dev tools. Once you find the element on which you need to keep hovering in the code displayed in dev tools, look on the right/bottom(depending on position of dev console)  so see the styles applied to it. There you will find a filter input. Next to it there is a button `:hov`. Click on that button, then it will show options to make the elements, active, focus, hover etc. This is temporary solution for more permanent solution you will either have to make a chrome extension or [tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) userscript.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! The site is called mylol.com. I added parts of the code

Comment: Take a look on your question, and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54603655/edit) your question correcting formatting of your code.